# Cannot open pdf document after installing April 2019 CU

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, pdf, cumulative-update

Installed [April 2019 CU](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4464514/april-9-2019-cumulative-update-for-sharepoint-enterprise-server-2013-k) last night(The updates was SharePoint 2013) and next day users are not able to open pdf documents. They get the following warning and when click on on OK, they will get the same warning for the second time and nothing happens:

[image]

Note that it is affecting IE 11 (32-bit). However, it works fine with Microsoft Edge, FireFox, Opera, and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is an ongoing "bug" with IE updates as there is a workaround mentioned the following two KB articles for IE Security Updates:

[Cumulative security update for Internet Explorer: March 12, 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4489873/cumulative-security-update-for-internet-explorer-march-12-2019)

[Cumulative security update for Internet Explorer: April 9, 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4493435/cumulative-security-update-for-internet-explorer-april-9-2019)